# Using latexdiff with TortoiseHg

Tags: latexdiff, versions, tortoisesvn

I am using [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) to track my Thesis document, and [latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff) to track differences in the document. To avoid saving the previous versions, I would like to combine latexdiff with tortoise  (Something similar to Using [latexdiff with git](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/using-latexdiff-with-git) or [latexdiff + version control](https://kwtrnka.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/latexdiff-version-control/) )

The command  `latexdiff -t UNDERLINE example-draft.tex example-rev.tex > example-diff.tex` on the [MWE from the manual](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/example) (both *.tex files compile successfully) is giving the following output.

```
    D:\User_Name\Latexdiff_Test>latexdiff -t UNDERLINE example-draft.tex example-rev.tex > example-diff.tex
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\includeonly{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latex
diff line 980.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(^(?:[^%\n]|\\%)*)\\bibliography{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scri
pts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1015.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(^(?:[^%\n]|\\%)*)\\subfile{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\l
atexdiff\latexdiff line 1030.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\\{ <-- HERE / at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line
1712.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}((?:(.(?!(?<!\\)\&|\\\\))*)?)\\end{MATHMODE}/ at C:\Program
 Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1987.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{MATHMODE}((?:(.(?!(?<!\\)\&|\\\\))*)?)\\end{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}/ at C:\Program
 Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1987.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}(.*?)\\end{MATHMODE}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\script
s\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1989.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{MATHMODE}(.*?)\\end{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\script
s\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1989.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\end{ <-- HERE SQUAREBRACKET}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latex
diff line 2070.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{ <-- HERE SQUAREBRACKET}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\lat
exdiff line 2071.
Negative repeat count does nothing at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 564, <DATA> line 22022.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)_{ <-- HERE ((?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{
(?:[^{}])*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1726.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\^{ <-- HERE ((?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\
{(?:[^{}])*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1729.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{ <-- HERE ((?:picture|tikzpicture|DIFnomarkup)[\w\d*@]*)}(.*?)\\end{\1}/ at C:
\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1736.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{((?:picture|tikzpicture|DIFnomarkup)[\w\d*@]*)}(.*?)\\end{ <-- HERE \1}/ at C:
\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1736.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{ <-- HERE ((?:array|[pbvBV]?matrix|smallmatrix|cases|split))}(.*?)\\end{\1}/ a
t C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1741.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{((?:array|[pbvBV]?matrix|smallmatrix|cases|split))}(.*?)\\end{ <-- HERE \1}/ a
t C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1741.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{ <-- HERE ((?:equation[*]?|displaymath|DOLLARDOLLAR)[*]?|(?:eqnarray|align|ali
gnat|gather|multline|flalign)[*]?|SQUAREBRACKET)}(.*?)\\end{\1}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1742.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{((?:equation[*]?|displaymath|DOLLARDOLLAR)[*]?|(?:eqnarray|align|alignat|gathe
r|multline|flalign)[*]?|SQUAREBRACKET)}(.*?)\\end{ <-- HERE \1}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1742.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\SUPERSCRIPT{ <-- HERE ((?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{
}]|\{(?:[^{}])*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 2075.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\SUPERSCRIPTNB{ <-- HERE ((?:[^{}])*)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexd
iff\latexdiff line 2076.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\SUBSCRIPT{ <-- HERE ((?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]|\{(?:[^{}]
|\{(?:[^{}])*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*\})*)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 2078.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\SUBSCRIPTNB{ <-- HERE ((?:[^{}])*)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdif
f\latexdiff line 2079.
```

---

Update:

updating latexdiff and using `latexdiff-vc --hg -r 2 --flatten PhD_Thesis.tex` is giving:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\zref\@newlabel{ <-- HERE DIFchgb(\d*)}{.*\\abspage{(\d*)}}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKT
eX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff-vc line 439.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\zref\@newlabel{DIFchgb(\d*)}{ <-- HERE .*\\abspage{(\d*)}}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKT
eX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff-vc line 439.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\zref\@newlabel{DIFchgb(\d*)}{.*\\abspage{ <-- HERE (\d*)}}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKT
eX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff-vc line 439.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\zref\@newlabel{ <-- HERE DIFchge(\d*)}{.*\\abspage{(\d*)}}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKT
eX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff-vc line 442.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\zref\@newlabel{DIFchge(\d*)}{ <-- HERE .*\\abspage{(\d*)}}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKT
eX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff-vc line 442.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\zref\@newlabel{DIFchge(\d*)}{.*\\abspage{ <-- HERE (\d*)}}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKT
eX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff-vc line 442.
Guess you are using HG ...
Working on  PhD_Thesis.tex
Checking out old dir into: C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Temp\wq_wy_2l70/latexdiff-vc-2 (rev: 2)
Running latexdiff
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\includeonly{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latex
diff line 980.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(^(?:[^%\n]|\\%)*)\\bibliography{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scri
pts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1015.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(^(?:[^%\n]|\\%)*)\\subfile{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\l
atexdiff\latexdiff line 1030.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\\{ <-- HERE / at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line
1712.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}((?:(.(?!(?<!\\)\&|\\\\))*)?)\\end{MATHMODE}/ at C:\Program
 Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1987.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{MATHMODE}((?:(.(?!(?<!\\)\&|\\\\))*)?)\\end{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}/ at C:\Program
 Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1987.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}(.*?)\\end{MATHMODE}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\script
s\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1989.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{MATHMODE}(.*?)\\end{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\script
s\latexdiff\latexdiff line 1989.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\end{ <-- HERE SQUAREBRACKET}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latex
diff line 2070.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\begin{ <-- HERE SQUAREBRACKET}/ at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\lat
exdiff line 2071.
Negative repeat count does nothing at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 564, <DATA> line 22022.
Unknown encoding 'ansinew' at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff\latexdiff line 859.
Something went wrong in latexdiff. Deleting PhD_Thesis-diff2.tex and abort
```

Comment: I don't use TortoiseHg but the name suggests you should try latexdiff-vc --hg option (only available in version 1.1.0 and up, though)

Comment: I have tried that, and I get exactly the same error

Comment: The errors you get indicate that something is fundamentally going wrong with the execution of latexdiff, as if a closing quote in the code appears to be overlooked. To debug, run latexdiff in stand-alone mode first. Try downloading a fresh copy of latexdiff from CTAN. If this still doesn't work you can send me a minimal failing example

Comment: I have run the command on the minimum working example, after downloading latexdiff into `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexdiff` and refreshing the FNDB. I have updated my post to include the error message with the MWE.

Comment: This should surely be working then. The only thing I can guess at is that there is a confusion between unix and dos line endings. Does "latexdiff -h" run and give you the help info. I am only familiar with the linux side of things, so hopefully someone from the DOS/Windows side can chip in.