# latexdiff sed: can`t read

Tags: latexdiff, git

I am running latexdiff on a file in a git repository with the following command `latexdiff-vc --git --force -r Versioning.tex --pdf` it starts but then the following message appears

```
Generated difference file Versioning-diff.tex
sed: can't read ;: No such file or directory
sed: can't read \mv: No such file or directory
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)
entering extended mode
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `Versioning-diff.tex;'.
<*> Versioning-diff.tex;
```

I can see that the file was generated in the folder, so I do not understand what is happening. Without the `--pdf` option the process completes without problems. Could someone help?

Comment: It tries to compile the file with a  `;` in the end ... If you are using a script for this check your script for linux commands that a `;` is by mistake inside the `' '`. In other case  it is a bug and the developers should be informed about that

Comment: The line in the latexdiff that fails is the following: 
`system("sed \"s/Package\\[dvips\\]/Package[pdftex]/\" \"$diff\" > \"$diff.tmp$$\" ; \\mv \"$diff.tmp$$\" \"$diff\"");`
When I run this the ; is interpreted as a command separator, and the \mv as a new command as intended. I realise they are different ways of writing this, but any idea why this does not work for @Szymon

Comment: @frederik ... Not exactly sure about what I am talking about... But I had a similar problem some time ago runing on a server some sequential commands (that was running ok localy). The solution was to enclose both of these commands inside `()` ... But I am not sure if this will solve the problem for you too (may be you could try ... It will not create problems in local run... and it will possibly solve this for servers ...)

Comment: @frederik - I am confused, I cannot find this line in my version of latexdiff (Version1.3.1.1.).  Could you tell me which line it is?

Comment: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/using-latexdiff-with-git?rq=1)

Comment: @Szymon The line is in latexdiff-vc not latexdiff.