# Having Access To Constantly Updated TeX Files

Tags: collaboration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simultaneous collaborative editing of a LaTeX file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/simultaneous-collaborative-editing-of-a-latex-file)

I was wondering what is the best way to share TeX files amongst a group of people per say. For example, you have a group of people working on a project and you want to have the files accessible to everyone in the group and also have a feature perhaps to alert the group when an edit has been made and what was the edit. I am working on a project involving multiple people and we are using multiple TeX files (i.e., project file) that includes a main file and several other smaller TeX files. I am just wondering what is the best way to communicate these files with everyone as we are all working on them. Perhaps maybe some forum, but it password protected where only members of the project can have access to make edits and such. I wanted all files to just be located in one central location instead of constant emailing files to everyone back and forth when changes were made. I am guessing this is a strategy that LaTeX developers use when creating say `LaTeX3` project.

Comment: Does [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/simultaneous-collaborative-editing-of-a-latex-file) help?

Comment: I would say @cmhughes link is a duplicate. In general I would recommend you to use a version control software.

Comment: The LaTeX3 project uses [version control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) (like any software project should use—and in my opinion also every writing project should use).

Comment: @cmhughes: Or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232/5763).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful comments. `:)`