# Indentation in AUCTEX and algorithmic package

Tags: indentation, algorithms, emacs, auctex

When working with EMACS+AUCTEX I encountered the problem of proper indentation when using the `algorithmic` package.

In this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \IF {list.first $\neq x_{min}$} 
  \STATE bla 
  \STATE bla 2
  \ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

I have a correct indentation, but hitting `C-c C-q C-e` in the algorithm's environment, produces:

```
\begin{algorithmic}
  \IF {list.first $\neq x_{min}$} \STATE bla \STATE bla 2
  \ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
```

When trying to add a nested if, I fail to obtain good indentation completely.

Does anyone know the problem? Possible solutions?

Comment: Simple answer: don't do `C-c C-q C-e`

Comment: @Seamus: but then, in the case of nested statements, I cannot get the proper indentation at all. `TAB` doesn't do the trick for some reason.

Comment: @Dror emacs indentation is smart, but it isn't perfect. Don't expect it to do everything for you. You may have to manually add spaces. Also, this seems to be a question about emacs, not about tex or friends.

Comment: You may have more luck on [superuser](http://superuser.com/search?q=emacs+indentation)

Comment: @Seamus: I can easily imagine that the answer is that there's no solution. This question however directly relates to AUCTeX (and the way it interacts with TeX related packages) which is in turn a friend of TeX.

Comment: @Dror but the problem is entirely on the emacs end and any solution would involve fixing _emacs_ not fixing anything TeX related. So I maintain that this is off topic here.

Comment: @Seamus: We had similar questions that were deemed to be on-topic (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/intelligent-paragraph-reflowing-in-vim). However, @Dror, there might be more emacs expertise available at superuser, so you might consider asking there if the question doesn't get answered here.

Comment: @Seamus:  The FAQ says:

If you have a question about ...

* (La)TeX related software and tools like BibTeX, LyX, LaTeX editors, viewers, and converters

... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

So, I guess it's really on topic here.

Comment: @ElmarZander I didn't say it was off topic. I said that Dror might have better luck getting _answers_ on superuser. I know emacs questions are on topic here, it's just that there don't seem to be that many people capable of _answering_ them here. So on topic or not, superuser might be a better place to ask them.

Comment: As this question is already 7 months old, maybe it is time to migrate it to superuser... :) Just as a side note, I really thought, and my experience so far showed, that TeX.SE is the place for such question. Such questions but not this one...

Comment: This problem can be solved but I guess it requires modification of the regexp that controls the indention such that it properly handles this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs is really smart about indentation. Unfortunately, you have to be even smarter to get it to do something new.

The easiest thing to do in this case is to customize the variable `LaTeX-paragraph-commands`. By default, this is empty. If you add IF and STATE, then `C-c C-q C-e` should respect your wishes and not jumble everything up together.

To do this, call `M-x customize-variable LaTeX-paragraph-commands`, click the `INS` button and add IF in the string box, click `INS` again and add `STATE` to a second string box. The click `apply and save`.

Getting proper indentation of nested IF statements is going to be trickier. One approach is to customize the variables `LaTeX-begin-regexp` and `LaTeX-end-regexp`. The first defaults to `begin\b`, and the second to `end\b`. If you extend them to `begin\b\|IF\b` and `end\b\|ENDIF\b` respectively, Auctex will indent your IF blocks how you like.

To do this, call `M-x customize-variable LaTeX-begin-regexp` and change `begin\b` to `begin\b\|IF\b`, and then click `apply and save`. Do the same for `LaTeX-end-regexp`, adding the `\|ENDIF\b` bit.

However, if you don't close your IF blocks with an ENDIF, then the indentation doesn't return to normal when you leave your algorithmic environment. To get Auctex to properly handle un-ended IF blocks, you need to cook up a custom indentation function. I don't know how to do that yet, but may return when I do.

Comment: Can you please add the code I should add to my `.emacs` in order to append what you suggested to my `LaTeX-paragraph-commands` variable?

Comment: You can do this with the customization tools, you don't need to modify your .emacs. See above.

Comment: @Tyler Is there a way to have it fix the indentation for \ELSE as well?

Answer (score 3):

Add `algorithmic` to `LaTeX-indent-environment-list`, no need to specify any function. Then it can indent it, but cannot do rebreaking of the lines.

While you are add it, might be an idea to add `tikzpicture` and `scope` to the list as well.

`M-x customize-variable LaTeX-indent-environment-list`

-then use the interface to add a new entry.

Comment: That will fix the problem of combining lines together (and nicely!), but it won't give provide automatic indentation of nested if statements, which is what I was referring to when I suggested you'd need a new indentation function.

Comment: With Emacs 26.3, I prefer to specify `current-indentation` as the function option, so that you're free to indent manually like in a `verbatim` environment...

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those who are interested in adding the code manually to the .emacs file.  I ran into to one issue that stumped me, so I think future readers may benefit from this. The following code suffices to fix indenting for `\IF`, `\FOR`, and `\LOOP`, as well as keeping each `\STATE` on it's own line.

```
(defun my-latex-mode-setup ()
  "Redefines and updates variables for various customizations."
  (setq LaTeX-paragraph-commands
      '("IF" "STATE" "LOOP" "FOR"))
  (setq LaTeX-begin-regexp
    (concat "begin\\b" "\\|IF\\b" "\\|LOOP\\b" "\\|FOR\\b"))
  (setq LaTeX-end-regexp
    (concat "end\\b" "\\|ENDIF\\b" "\\|ENDLOOP\\b" "\\|ENDFOR\\b"))
  (setq LaTeX-paragraph-commands-regexp (LaTeX-paragraph-commands-regexp-make)))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-latex-mode-setup)
```

Each of the `setq` calls redefines the same variables that were set with Customize in the other answer, except the last one that modifies `LaTeX-paragraph-commands-regexp`.

This last `setq` modifies an internal variable that is generated by a call to `LaTeX-paragraph-commands-regexp-make` which combines the additional commands in the list `LaTeX-paragraph-commands` with an internal list of commands defined in the variable `LaTeX-paragraph-commands-internal`.

Updating the variable `LaTeX-paragraph-commands-regexp` is necessary because the original call to `LaTeX-paragraph-commands-regexp-make` happens before the hook in your .emacs file is called.  Without it `LaTeX-paragraph-commands-regexp` does not contain the new commands defined in `LaTeX-paragraph-commands`.

Last, for those not familiar with emacs regular expressions, the double back slashes `\\` are important to make sure that the strings are correctly read as regular expressions.