# LaTeX from Scientific Workplace

Tags: conversion, scientific-workplace

I am using this program "Scientific Workplace", which seems to have a proprietary-non-standard version of LaTeX, i.e., a version that cannot be readily interpreted by standard Latex readers; I uploaded a `.tex` workplace file to someone who has a LaTeX reader, and no matter how he tried to open it, all he got was a garbled mess.

Does anyone know how to go around this, i.e., does anyone now if there is a special way of saving a file in Sci Workplace, or some other trick so that a Sci. Workplace-version Latex file can be  read by standard LaTeX readers?

Comment: I think this question should rather be asked on tex.SE. See also this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100/

Answer (score 15):

SWP users have to re-save their work as `Portable LaTeX` in order for it to be compilable using normal LaTeX dists. and even then there may be packages in the preamble that are not found in normal LaTeX dists. These packages can often just be deleted (the document still compiles without them).

Answer (score 3):

Even without saving as Portable LaTeX, SWP files will compile provided TeX has access to the file TCILatex. When saved as Portable LaTeX, they will compile on any system that has access to the standard AMS packages and graphicx. And some of us know "real LaTeX" but prefer not to work in TeX code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider switching to the TexWorks editor that is included in the TexLive distribution. Using that editor and the TexLive distribution would not pose the problem you describe.

Comment: For some users it may be a better choice to switch to real LaTeX, but for others it is not a good idea. Learning LaTeX takes time, and some people are not willing to invest this time.