# Scientific Word converter?

Tags: word-to-latex

**Are there any converters that can take a Scientific Word code and make it pure LaTeX code?**

Don't read what follows: 
Below this line is some nonsense I had to write in order to be able to ask the question.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Scientific Word is different from Microsoft Word.

Comment: My apologies for that.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14098/latex-from-scientific-workplace

Comment: Have you tried saving the file (within SWP) as "portably latex". Apart from a few comment lines, that's basically pure latex code.