# Is there such a thing as a LaTeX code formatter

Tags: tools, sourcecode

I was looking for this a while back for JavaScript, but I was wondering a general purpose one exists for all, or most languages.

For example for LaTeX I would put the following in a text box

```
$f_i^k+10=x$
```

and it spits out the better formatted version

```
%%%
%% Insert comment describing function here
%%%
$ f_{i}^{k} + 10 = x $
```

I can't be the only person on the planet that does not wish to go through a massive .tex file and fix these tedious problems.

Comment: @dmckee this is too funny, on the linke bdares provided, someone has further complained "This should probably be community wiki". I imagine if I checked the community wiki it will claim that it should probably belong on a blog...

Comment: There is no guarantee that a question will find a good fit on the Stack Exchange network. In any case bdares link is not specifically about pretty printing now about literate programming/in-line documentation, so it may or may not be a duplicate. I'm not active enough on TeX.SE to be certain.

Comment: @puk You misunderstand the comment. It merely means that the answers should belong to the community, instead of to individual users (it’s a Stack Overflow feature). The question bdares links to is fine, and so is yours.

Comment: @puk: Are you interested in "correcting" your LaTeX code (in the `.tex` file) so that super-/subscripts are actually put in braces `{ }`, thereby possibly avoiding formatting problems?

Comment: @Werner I'm interested in an automatic code fixer upper which also aids in avoiding potential formatting problems.

Comment: @puk: Since super/subscripts may contain expressions and are therefore not limited to single character elements, it would be difficult to generalize code clean-up. [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) might be able to do some of the grouping based on certain assumptions. But such rules would be source-specific; again, not very general.

Comment: I think you could use [blacktex](https://github.com/nschloe/blacktex) on the lines of [black formatter for python](https://github.com/psf/black) by [Nico Schlömer](https://github.com/nschloe). See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602715/

Comment: This should be linked with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100/86

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a website that formats the latex code to make indents look correct.

The general idea of the website is to make sure you can read the code.
It also provides table indentations. I am still looking to see if adding an empty comment block for formulas is possible.

https://c.albert-thompson.com/latex-pretty/

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [TeXpretty](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/texpretty/). I have used it a couple of times for cleaning up messy code and it does a decent job.

Answer (score 6):

As of Version 3.7, `latexindent.pl` can help with this.

*As a warning: do take care when using regular expressions such as those below, always check that they are behaving as you would like, and test them before using them on anything important.*

Starting with the following sample code

```
\begin{env}
$f_i^k+10=x$
\end{env}
$g_ij^12-3=x$
```

and the `YAML` file, say `puk1.yaml`

```
replacements:
  -
    substitution: |-
      s/\$(.*?)\$/%%
            %% Insert comment describing function here
            %%
            \$$1\$/sxg
```

and running the command

```
latexindent.pl -r myfile.tex -l=puk1.yaml
```

gives the output:

```
\begin{env}
    %%
    %% Insert comment describing function here
    %%
    $f_i^k+10=x$
\end{env}
%%
%% Insert comment describing function here
%%
$g_ij^12-3=x$
```

This doesn't have everything you requested. We can incorporate some more replacements in the following file, say `puk2.yaml`

```
replacements:
  -
    substitution: |-
      s/\$\h*(.*?)\h*\$/#
            my $comment = "%%\n%% Insert comment describing function here\n%%\n";
            my $body = $1;
            # add braces to superscripts and subscripts
            $body =~ s@(\^|\_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@$1\{$2\}@sg;
            # add a single space around + - =
            $body =~ s@\h*([+\-=])\h*@ $1 @sg;
            # put it all together
            $comment."\$ ".$body." \$";/sxge
```

and running

```
latexindent.pl -r myfile.tex -l=puk2.yaml
```

gives

```
\begin{env}
    %%
    %% Insert comment describing function here
    %%
    $ f_{i}^{k} + 10 = x $
\end{env}
%%
%% Insert comment describing function here
%%
$ g_{ij}^{12} - 3 = x $
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on VS code, try **latex-formatter**.

Comment: I think this used latexindent behind the scenes :) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nickfode.latex-formatter

Comment: @cmhughes yea that's right

Answer (score 1):

this online [formatter](https://latex-editor.pages.dev/formatter/) could help you.