# Autoformatting latex source code?

Tags: texworks

I'm writing some mathematical formulas and I wonder if I can autoformat them.
Here is an example:

```
\( {n(1+\frac {1} n)n(1+\frac {2} n)...n(1+\frac {10} n) \over n(1-\frac {1} n)n(1-\frac {2} n)...n(1-\frac {10} n)} =  \frac{n^{10}}{n^{10}} = 1 \)
```

Do you know what this thing means? I have no idea also, I have to compile it, to see the content.
What I want is to recognize it from source code for fast editing.
Any chance that I can have this kind of feature for offline editor?
I'm using TeXworks right now.

Comment: @Raven yes, it is. Thank you

Comment: You can also have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30595/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-latex-code-formatter - I have used [latexindent](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl) a bit and found it quite useful. You'll have to put some time in to create a format spec though (if you are not content with the defaults)

Comment: Not sure what has been asked exactly and therefore if this is really a duplicate, but RStudio in Rmarkdow document show previews of the LateX  formulas without compiling the whole document. Other alternative could be use a LaTeX editor with live preview (e.g.: Gummi) or LyX, that in math mode is a nearly WYSIWYG editor (even if you don't  want write the whole  document in LyX, it could be useful to get the source of the formula code and then paste in your editor).

Comment: TeXStudio does also have a preview of formulas (I think it is enabled by default. If not it can be enabled in the settings)