# Automatic source document formatting

Tags: tools, sourcecode, cleanup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for cleaning LaTeX code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100/tool-for-cleaning-latex-code)

This might not be a TeX question, strictly speaking but I'm sure this is the right forum to ask this: Is there a tool that can format the (La)TeX source documents? To clarify, I'm not trying to typeset TeX sourcecode in output documents -- I have `listings`, `algorithms` and `minted` for that. I'm trying to find a tool that can format my source `.tex` documents so that they have better indentation etc.

Comment: emacs doesn't do too badly. `indent-region` is the command you want. I find the 'LaTeX' mode to format code much better than 'TeX' mode.

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping for a more general tool as I don't use emacs. (I'm on TeXstudio)

Comment: Latexindent is cross platform, cross editor, conda enabled, docker enabled, pre-commit enabled