# Command to format latex source code?

Tags: formatting

I've been typsetting this last weeks and my code looked like something garbage. I wouldn't want to manually format this as it is tedious, and I wondered if there is such command to format latex source code automatically?

Sure I can format C language with `indent` or `clang-format` but how about tex files?

Googling end me up empty handed.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100/86 look helpful?

Comment: That seemed to work. I believe it's better to automate this with a makefile. Though I'm still open if there's an easier method without requiring to run latex->dvips->fmtlatex->latex->dvips.

Comment: see latexindent (which you could call from a makefile of course)  (do you have a special reason to use latex/dvipsps2pdf ? most people use pdflatex )

Comment: I meant, "That seemed to work. I believe it's better to automate this long procedure of running 5 commands in a Makefile.". It was mentioned to create dvi from tex, not to compile it into pdf. I do use pdflatex. About latexindent, I see that's a possible solution, but due to my unmaintained unix OS and packages, running the perl script has provided me cryptic messages which then requires downloading extra packages in my unmaintained system. I hoped something like a command written in a compiled language (like standard C) with no required extra dependencies as I'm tight on space. But thank you.

Comment: Latexindent can be called from Conda or docker